# Webpack "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot' "

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, webfonts

I successfully configured webpack for js and sass. It works well until I import font into scss file. I will try to show it in code below.

My webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
    },
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/src/js/adminMain.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/dist/'),
        filename: 'adminBundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            },
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader"
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                        implementation: require("sass")
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    plugins: [

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "adminBundle.css"
        }),
        new MinifyPlugin()

    ]


};
```

Admin.scss

```
// Variables
@import "./variables/admin.scss";
@import "./fontawesome.min.css";
@import "./solid.scss";

ALL OTHER NORMAL CSS.....
```

And this is solid.scss

```
/*!
 * Font Awesome Free 5.9.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
 * License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
 */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: auto;
  src: url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot");
  src: url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

.fa,
.fas {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900; }
```

Well, visual studio code plugin watch-sass can resolve it without problems. But now i am using instead webpack. When I didn't import solid.scss it works well but when I import solid.scss I am starting getting errors probably it cant works with fonts files. But I don't know how to fix it. I will be thankful for any advice.

This is example of error

```
 ERROR in ./public/src/css/admin.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-3!./public/src/css/admin.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot' in 'C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXX\Praca\Webové aplikácie\nodeCMS\public\src\css'
     @ ./public/src/css/admin.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4-3!./public/src/css/admin.scss) 5:38-77 6:38-77
```

Comment: To manage all those files (.eot, .ttf, .png, .jpg...) I use file-loader https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/. Try to use also that loader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works !!!

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const BabelMinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
    },
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/src/js/adminMain.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/dist/'),
        filename: 'adminBundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [{
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                    }, {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "postcss-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        },
                        options: {
                            implementation: require("sass")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|gif|woff|woff2)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                }]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "adminBundle.css"
        }),

    ]

};
```

variables.scss

```
$fa-font-path: "../../webfonts" !default;
...
```

solid.scss

```
/*!
 * Font Awesome Free 5.9.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
 * License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
 */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.eot');
  src: url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.woff') format('woff'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome') format('svg');
}

.fa,
.fas {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

admin.scss

```
// Variables
@import "./variables/admin.scss";
@import "./fontawesome.min.css";
@import "./solid.scss";
```

.....

Just needed to do some changes in scss files and now it works. `{$fa-font-path}` is the key. Why just cant be anything in webdev easy.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and as you point out $fa-font-path is the main problem here.
I solved it with a @using statement that overrides its default value without touching node_modules file like so:




<pre><code>
use "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid" with (
    $fa-font-path: "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts"
);
</code></pre>
Hope it helpes someone

Answer (score 15):

In my case the error was:

```
Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome
```

And I fixed it, adding this to my index.scss

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims';
```

> note the "~" in $fa-font-path

and this to my webpack.config

```
{
  test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue fixing by modifying path from your source scss or css file.

If your directory tree look like example below:

```
src
    fontawesome/
        scss/
            fontawesome.scss
    style.scss
```

You need to import this files like this:

@import "./fontawesome/scss/fontawesome.scss";

like your path starting from your style.scss file and you won't need to modify path in your variables.scss file